# Why is DNS Forwarder not resolving/working?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008, domain-controller, internal-dns

I just installed a Win 2008 Remote DC in one of our sites. For the DNS setting, it's using 127.0.0.1 as it's Primary and 10.1.1.2 (this is our AD/DNS in the Main HQ) as Secondary. We have some internal websites that are not resolvable using this DNS 10.1.1.2 server, which is why we added another internal BIND DNS server 10.1.1.9 as FORWARDER.

From a client machine, if I do an nslookup - 10.1.1.9 I can resolve these internal-only websites in question without problems.

However, if I use the default DNS (which is the Remote DC) I will get an error. Is this due to the FORWARDER not working or I missed something else? Recursion is "on".

Comment: Where do the DNS records for these internal websites reside? Do they reside in one of the zones on your internal DNS servers?

Comment: You should fix whatever is keeping the DNS server `10.1.1.2` from resolving the internal websites.

Comment: To make a long story short, we were acquired by another company who is using BIND. They own this 10.1.1.9 server and we have no access (yet). The zone files for these internal web sites are on 10.1.1.9. What I don't understand is why 10.1.1.9 doesn't work as a FORWARDER?

Comment: This Microsoft technote probably answer my question:  "A forwarder is a Domain Name System (DNS) server on a network that forwards DNS queries for external DNS names to DNS servers outside that network. [link] https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730756(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think that your DC with server 127.0.0.1 can be configured in the Forwarders tab in DNS admin tool option to get the 10.1.1.2 or any google (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4)  in that order in the forwarder order. you did not need to deploy the 10.1.1.9 as a forwarder.

The internal sites should be its respective record in their own zones (if they differ from the main "domain name".

Internal sites are meant to be resolved internally and external sites are meant to use the forwarders to get their queries.

Comment: This is probably part of the puzzle. This is an example web site that is only  available internally:

Comment: This is probably part of the puzzle. The domain name is the same for our own DNS 10.1.1.2 and this BIND 10.1.1.9.  To explain further, here's an example of internal-only website: "reports.mydomain.com". This can only be resolved on 10.1.1.9. However, other URLs like "schedule.mydomain.com" is resolvable only on 10.1.1.2.